# Filtering Google Earth Engine image collection by filename using wildcards

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, filter, sentinel-2

I am new to GEE and now I need to filter and sort a sentinel 2 data collection by cloud coverage. Basically, I need the Ecuador tile with "T17MNT" in its id in image properties. I figure out the workflow should be something like the following, but I still have issues with the Filter.

1. How do I use a wildcard in gee?

There are lots of images but I just want those that have "T17MNT" in "PRODUCT_ID". T17MNT stands for the granule identifier in Eduador. EE asset ids for Sentinel-2 L2 assets have the following format: COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20151128T002653_20151128T102149_T56MNN. **The final 6-character** string is a unique granule identifier. But other digits are dates and times and I don't want them in my filter. I assume the wildcard is something like "?T17MNT?".

2. This is the link to the [sentinel 2 dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR#description). See "image properties" tab. "PRODUCT_ID" might not be the correct field that contains the long name described above. but please ignore that for now, or let me know the correct one.

This is the error I receive.

```
ImageCollection (Error)
Filter.inList: Cannot filter using 'ListContains' with 'T17MNT' as a left operand.
```

This is the code I am using.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2020-05-23', '2020-10-25')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 16))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('PRODUCT_ID', 'T17MNT'))
                  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', false)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.filter(ee.Filter.stringContains('PRODUCT_ID','T17MNT'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You `ee.Filter.inList()` requires the filter value to be a List. When reaching an error it helps to read the documentation to see what your input format should be. To answer your question it can look like this:

```
    .filter(ee.Filter.inList('PRODUCT_ID', ee.List(['T17MNT'])))
```

But that doesn't result in an image so I guess you need to use a different property that defines the tiles you are searching for, not sure but perhaps check out options like this:

```
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE', '21NXG'))
.filterBounds(geometry) // ==> filter on a geometry
```